# Amazon Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, iis

I have a website with API. Created 2 instances for web UI and 2 instances for web API. I wanna create ELB for web UI instances. Which one do I need to create? application, network or classic? All traffic must be secure (SSL/https). web UI instances with IIS. Should have a lot of domain and subdomain with SSL.

Second question: I need ELB with a secure connection. So I wanna create a certificate on Amazon. When I create cert amazon asked which domain I have. But it will be ELB with DNS name for example myELBAFwEGewff.aws2.com. If I will have a lot of domains on IIS how ELB will be work?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

AWS ELB does not play nicely with endpoints outside of their infrastructure. Where you have the stuff on IIS, you would need to leverage a vendor-agnostic load balancing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Created Application Load balancer.
Created 2 machines for UI and 2 for API.
ALso setup SSL for domail and setup route for machine and subdomains.
Didn't create https on IIS. Just created 443 on balancer and 80 on ec2.
Everything works fine.